# Grails Test-App Tries to Insert Updated Tables Instead of Update Them

Tags: grails

I have been building our grails app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk through Jenkins for awhile now without issue, jumping and building between branches for years. This became an issue, though, when adding the grails test suite into the build.

I set up a test database for jenkins to use itself and let grails populate all the table data on its own, it worked for several months until recently when I decided to deploy a branch that was around 6 months old to one of our development environments. As you can guess, a branch 6 months old was missing some columns that were in more recent releases, and hence in the database, so grails deleted those columns, and tested and deployed without issue.

The problem arose when I went to deploy a more recent branch to a different environment, and grails test-app started failing due to sql errors because the app was trying to use a column that didn't exist on that table.

I dug into it further and discovered in the logs that when grails should have been trying to update the tables because they already existed and just needed a column added, it was trying to insert the tables instead. Obviously this caused issue with the tables already existing and the database not being updated.

Does anyone have any knowledge on how to force grails test-app to update the database tables instead of try to insert them? This has never happened in the use of the app, so I know this is localized to an issue with the test-suite, but the documentation on it is kind of bad, especially for grails 2.3.11 so I can't find anything.

Comment: Are you using `dbCreate="create-drop"` for test env as it's described in https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.3.11/guide/single.html#dataSource ?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc Sorry about the late response, got caught up and forgot to respond. In our DataSource.groovy file we do have the `test` environment showing `dbCreate='create-drop'` so I'm not sure what the issue could be that would cause it to not drop. May try normal create tomorrow? I see that on success it drops the tables for create-drop but if it fails, does that mean it doesn't drop them even on the next startup?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc So I tried changing the dcCreate to create and got the same errors, but updating it to "update" works fine, so for some reason it's just not dropping the tables as intended I believe? I did check and the old branch that was deployed that broke this uses a dbCreate value of "update", though so I'm not sure if that broke it.

Comment: It's hard to say what's happening without an access to this database and checking what're the differences in the structure with applied "update" or with "create-drop". Have you checked carefully the logs?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc Yeah it's odd. I was able to fix it here but it was that the old branch that was tested had a dbCreate value of "Update" but then when switched back to the new branch the dbCreate was "create-drop" so for some reason if it's run as update, it won't drop the tables in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being due to the old branch that was deployed having a different dbCreate value for the test environment, so for some reason when it made it's changes with the dbCreate property of "update" then switched back to "create-drop" it no longer could drop the tables before re-adding them.